# How to configure environment variables in an IIS 7 application?

Tags: windows, iis, environment-variables, user-profile

I need to set the environment variable `COMPLUS_FORCEENC=1` in an ASP.NET application. This variable must be set at the time the worker process starts to have an effect.

Therefore, I did this:

1. Create a new user using the Computer Management console.
2. Set a password.
3. Make sure it is a member of `Users` and `IIS_IUSRS`.
4. Configure the IIS Application Pool to use that user and load the user profile. This is using a custom pool, not the default one.
5. Log in as that user to set the variable.
6. Relogin to make sure the variable is set.
7. Restart the OS.
8. Make sure the application loads and works.

Unfortunately, the ASP.NET app does not see the variable. I printed the whole environment from within the app.

When I use Process Explorer on the worker process I see that it runs under the correct user but the variable is not set. Also, the `TEMP` variable points to `C:\Windows\Temp` and not (as expected) to the user profile's temp directory (which exists). I understand this is a sign of the user profile not being loaded.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist` shows the hive of that user loaded. The `Environment` key for that user appears to be populated correctly:

[image]

What did I do wrong? How can I make the variable appear?

This is a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 6):

> Windows 7 SP1 introduced a new default setting for IIS that prevents the loading of profile specific environment variables for IIS application pools.

So, for Windows 7 SP1 you additionally need to edit the following file:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

and add a `processModel` element with `setProfileEnvironment` set to `true` for your site app pool in the `applicationPools` section.

It should look like this:

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
      <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

See [Windows 7 SP1 causes IntelliTrace Collection to fail on IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547655) for more details.

Note: You should edit the `applicationHost.config` file with admin rights and after the change you should reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just set/create the environment variable within an asp.net page

like:

```
 System.Environment.SetEnvironmentvariable("myvar", "my value", System.EnvironmentvariableTarget.user)
```

this should survive AppPool recycles and even server reboots.

I have a full working example at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/672726/in-iis7-is-it-possible-to-have-custom-environment-variables-per-web-site/672807#672807)

Comment: I saw your post. I now tried setting the variable. This does not change anything. Using Procmon I see that the variable is set to exactly the location where it previously was set. After `iisreset` the variable still is not there.

Comment: @boot4life - I just tested this under Windows 7, using the script in my linked answer. The environment variable survives an iisreset and a reboot. Are you sure you set `loadUserProfile` to true in the AppPool properties? I'm not using a normal user but `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and as the Process Model Identity.

Comment: I will try not using a normal user and report back. I'm sure loadProfile is set. I confirmed this by grepping apphost.config.

Comment: I create a new pool, set it to AppPoolIdentity, LoadProfile is default-enabled. I made the app execute the code that you provided. The variable is still not set (according to the app and to procexp). What could cause IIS to silently fail to load user profiles?

Comment: sorry I have no idea, why it doesn't work for you, it always worked for me.